# How do I upgrade Ubuntu OS from 32 to 64 bit?

Tags: system-installation

I chose to install the 32 bit version of Desktop ubuntu but due to my lack of knowldege I realised that **many softwares were incompatible with the 32 bit version** and therefore I needed to use a 64 bit one instead.
Before getting ready to do a clean install of 64bit ubuntu Desktop I wanted to ask if there is **an other way of upgrading my operating system without needing to do a clean install of it**. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the OP of free -m pls?

Comment: Raphael & Soren A I dont care about my data guys everything i want is stored into my onecloud.Anyways thank you so much for trying but i think ima go for the clean install.Love this ubuntu forums <3!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically, you cannot upgrade an OS from 32 bit to 64 bit but there is a workaround: [Aptik](http://www.teejeetech.in/2016/04/upgrade-to-ubuntu-1604-with-aptik.html).

- Install Aptik:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:teejee2008/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install aptik
  ```
- Run, Aptik.
- Backup all the required data.
- Install new Ubuntu 64 bit.
- Install Aptik.
- Restore everything.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can upgrade from older to newer versions of Ubuntu, but not from 32 to 64 bit. Even if it were possible, you could face so many unexpected hardware surprises so I would strongly recommend you go for a clean install.

[Here's the link for Ubuntu 16.04.2 Desktop 64-bit iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso).

Answer (score 0):

If your Ubuntu is recently installed, the easiest way it to make a copy of your data, if any, to an USB stick, and then install Ubuntu 64 bit version using the same partitions you are using for your 32 bit installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is distrorejuve tool capable of doing this:
https://blog.rimuhosting.com/2018/03/21/32-to-64-bit-distro-crossgrades/

It is called distrorejuve and may help with crossgrade process (while still in beta). `--to-64bit` switch is doing it; see `--help` for details

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Added tool name and relevant command line options.